# Login module for Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to login to a website and run some tests. There are so many links that I need to click and other tasks are to be performed on the webpages.
I wrote a python script that takes the command line arguments (browser, username and password) and logs in to the website. This works fine. 
The login module needs to be imported into other scripts where I can perform the tests using this Login module.

testlogin.py

```
import sys
import argparse
from selenium import webdriver

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('browser', default='chrome', help='Types of browser:chrome, firefox, ie')
parser.add_argument('username', help='This is the username')
parser.add_argument('password', help='This is the password')
args = parser.parse_args()

setup_parameters = sys.argv[1:]


class Testsite(object):


      test_url = 'someurl'

# Initialization Method
    def __init__(self):
        self.username = setup_parameters[1]
        self.password = setup_parameters[2]
        if setup_parameters[0] == 'chrome':
            self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
            print("Running tests on Chrome browser")
            self.browser.implicitly_wait(15)
            self.premier_login()
            self.premier_close()
        elif setup_parameters[0] == 'ie':
            self.browser = webdriver.Ie()
            print("Running tests on Internet Explorer browser")
            self.browser.implicitly_wait(15)
            self.premier_login()
            self.premier_close()
        elif setup_parameters[0] == 'firefox':
            self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
            print("Running tests on Firefox browser")
            self.browser.implicitly_wait(15)
            self.premier_login()
            self.premier_close()
        elif setup_parameters[0] == 'None':
            print('No browser type specified.... continuing with the default browser')
            self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()

#Method to login to the site

    def site_login(self):
        self.browser.get(self.test_url)
        self.browser.find_element_by_id("Username").send_keys(self.username)
        self.browser.find_element_by_id("Password").send_keys(self.password)
        self.browser.find_element_by_id("btnLogin").click()
        self.browser.maximize_window()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(10)

# Closing the browser window and terminating the test
    def site_close(self):
        self.browser.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    Testsite().site_login()
```

How do I set the driver from the above module, if I want to import it to the other scripts.

I tried importing the above module into other scripts but wasn't able to set the driver.

Comment: after import into other script, the driver should be available as `testlogin.Testsite().browser`, returns `<selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="515c2d4235b3ed3a133399ff138e0739")>` on my machine

Comment: Thanks! @davedwards, I was trying something else.

Comment: Welcome @dev-bin hopefully that works for your needs. If not [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52302970/edit) the question and add more information.

Comment: @davedwards, When I run the script i get the following error, I tried to catch the exception but doesn't seem to work.
C:\>python testlogin.py chrome user password
[15256:13268:0913/164925.682:ERROR:install_util.cc(603)] Failed to read HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken: 
File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=55905): Max retries exceeded with url: